# Visual Studio 2022 - Strange C++ Coloring/Highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2022, syntax-highlighting

I have a strange problem with C++ syntax coloring in the Visual Studio 2022. Default coloring of the syntax such as `[]` `<<` is set to be green, but sometimes Visual Studio colors it differently, e.g. blue or gray as in this picture:

[image: color problem]

I haven't been able to find the reason for this, the only way it works was to completely disable the IntelliSense, but I'd like to avoid doing this because it makes other things not to work, such as uint64_t type coloring etc.

Is it a problem with Visual Studio and not the programing itself?

Edit: Here it is far better to see
[The Problem, Better Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLKs7.png)

Comment: Have you looked in Tools → Options → Fonts and Colors to see if a related setting is changed to this green for some reason? Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: I have no extension, or at least I didn't install them, I instaled only the basic VS Comunity. The problem occurs not only at this chars, it occurs at << too. I think it's not about the highlighting, but rather about the IntelliSense, because when I turn it off, the problem disappears.

Comment: I've added another example, where is it far better to see. Thanks for your time, Timothy!